# How to generate maps

Tags: html, canvas, 2d-games

I am creating a html5 canvas game. I cannot figure out how to perform the generation of such maps.

All maps of different size and scale. How does it work?

[image: example map]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of resource about HTML 5 game

Here is one [Build a tile-based HTML5 game](http://www.creativebloq.com/html5/build-tile-based-html5-game-31410992)

Or you wanna to use some Js engine perhaps? http://www.kiwijs.org/api/

Hope this would help you